# Removing a specific jquery effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have searched all over the site, but due to my low knowledge I was unable to find the right words. I am working my website and the script I was using had a previous theme.

I did a lot of changes so far and I am totally satisfied with it.

However there is a effect which I think from jquery whom sometimes brake my design. I want to remove this effect but couldnt find how. The effect is, when your cursor comes on certain links and buttons, they get bigger and kinda zoomed.

Here is the example of it, http://www.uluyemek.com/demo/

If you look on the left sidebar and get your mouse on the "Giriş Yap" which means log in, the image gets bigger, I would really like to delete this since its causing problems on other pages, to me.

Please help me find where the jquery hide itself.

Comment: you have to paste the code to your question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That effect is being handled by CSS3 transforms applied to that button.

Remove the following CSS from the button and it will make the effect stop:

```
-webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
```